# Best way to identify Internet Explorer 11 and Internet Explorer 10 based on user agent

Tags: internet-explorer, web

I want to know what's the best way to identify the different Internet Explorer version based on the user agent.

What I seen so far is that the user agent of Internet Explorer 11 (native mode) is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

The configuration for Internet Explorer 10 is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)
```

So, the question is: ¿Locating this "Trident/7.0" is a good way to detect if a browser is Internet Explorer 11??

Comment: Consider detecting features instead of specific browsers unless you deal with browser-specific bugs you’re going to workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: It can be, with certain caveats. There's no definitive answer and this is one reason why browser sniffing is widely discouraged.

Longer answer: [The IE user agent string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx) varies under different conditions.  IE11's Enterprise Mode, for example, reports an IE8 user agent string.  (The linked article provides a relatively exhaustive list of variations.)

The general recommendation is to use feature detection, progressive enhancement, and graceful fallback to delivery a content experience for browsers that don't support certain features.  Alternatively, there may be a polyfill or alternate approach that helps.  [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/) is a good resource for figuring out alternatives.

Comment: That stuff of progressive enhancement and graceful fallback it's the ideal objective. In an ideal world I would do that. But unfortunately I have a short budget and a legacy application that need to support newer browsers. The point you make that under certain conditions the browser can change its user agent doesn't bother me, because it is expected that the browser behaves accordingly. What I want is to detect the native user agent of these browsers.

Comment: Sadly, the user agent string is not a reliable indicator of that.  It varies according to the nearby conditions.  The Trident token is the most reliable approach, but--again--not 100%.  In your situation, I would consider testing for the two values you mentioned as pass conditions and adding recovery code in case neither matches.  It could be as simple as putting together a warning page with steps to try to fix.